# In Mint 19.1, how do I bond an ethernet and a wifi adapter?

Tags: networking, linux-mint, network-interface, networkmanager, bonding

In Mint 19.1, I can see in "Network Connections" that I can bond 2 ethernet adapters. How do I bond an ethernet adapter and a wifi one without completely disabling the GUI configuration of networks?

EDIT: I noticed that there is a [similar question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/272935/bonding-wired-and-wireless-while-using-network-manager) (with no complete answer) for a much older version of Linux Mint (17.3).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Disable your ethernet connection
2. Ensure you wifi connection is activated
3. Execute the following commands replacing myeth0 with your ethernet device, mywifi0 with your wifi device, MYSSID with your wifi network and MYWIFIPASSWORD with your wifi password:

```
nmcli con add type bond con-name bond ifname bond0 mode active-backup primary myeth0 +bond.options "fail_over_mac=active,miimon=100,primary_reselect=always,updelay=200"
nmcli con add type wifi con-name bond-wlan slave-type bond master bond0 ifname mywifi0 ssid MYSSID
nmcli c modify bond-wlan wifi-sec.key-mgmt wpa-psk wifi-sec.psk MYWIFIPASSWORD
nmcli con add type ethernet con-name bond-eth slave-type bond master bond0 ifname myeth0
nmcli c up bond
```

4. You may also need to do the following if they aren't automatically started:

```
nmcli c up bond-eth
nmcli c up bond-wifi
```